# How to Deserialize unknown primitive json property type using Gson

Tags: java, json, gson, deserialization

What is the best way to deserialize using Gson a simple JSONObject (or JSONArray) but the "value" property can be of integer, boolean or string type

```
{"label":"Label", "value":56}
{"label":"Label", "value":false}
{"label":"Label", "value":"string value"}
```

with class

```
public class ViewPair {
    @SerializedName("label")
    private String label;
    @SerializedName("value")
    private <Unknown> value;
```

As advised by Deadpool, I tried JsonPrimitive type but get error whenever I want to get a value from ViewPair like this:

```
Gson gson=new Gson();
List<ViewPair>data = gson.fromJson(array.toString(), listType);
JSONObject object = item.getJSONObject("value");
String spinnerLabel=object.getString("label");
JsonPrimitive spinnerValue=(JsonPrimitive) object.get("value");<-error
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to com.google.gson.JsonPrimitive
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can parse it as [JsonPrimitive](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6.2/com/google/gson/JsonPrimitive.html) since it has methods to check type [isBoolean](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6.2/com/google/gson/JsonPrimitive.html#isBoolean--), [isNumber](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6.2/com/google/gson/JsonPrimitive.html#isNumber--) and [isString](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6.2/com/google/gson/JsonPrimitive.html#isString--) as well as methods to get the value

```
public class ViewPair {

   @SerializedName("label")
   private String label;

   @SerializedName("value")
   private JsonPrimitive value;

}
```

Here is the example i haves test these three scenarios

```
ViewPair targetObject1 = new Gson().fromJson("{\"label\":\"Label\", \"value\":56}", ViewPair.class);
ViewPair targetObject2 = new Gson().fromJson("{\"label\":\"Label\", \"value\":false}", ViewPair.class);
ViewPair targetObject3 = new Gson().fromJson("{\"label\":\"Label\", \"value\":\"string value\"}", ViewPair.class);
```

From `JsonObject` you can directly get the `JsonPrimitive`

```
JsonPrimitive object = item.getAsJsonPrimitive("value");
```

And from `JsonPrimitive` you can get the value in required type

```
object.getAsString()
object.getAsInt()
object.getAsBoolean()
```

Comment: thanks but I get error  java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.google.gson.JsonPrimitive when  JSONObject object = item.getJSONObject("value");  JsonPrimitive spinnerValue=(JsonPrimitive)object.get("value");

Comment: you should not do type casting, use `getAsJsonPrimitive` on `JsonElement` to get primitive type https://javadoc.io/static/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6.2/com/google/gson/JsonElement.html#getAsJsonPrimitive--, and if you have any questions please update the code with error message in above post @Taha